# Code Editor Permission On Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

how do I give my code editor permission to save to "opt/lampp/htdocs" on my Ubuntu system?

Comment: add your user to the group that owns the directory (adduser <username> <groupname>; newgrp)

Answer (score -2):

If running from the command line, preface the command to start your code editor with `sudo`. For instance, if you're using Geany, the command would be:

`sudo geany`

`sudo` allows you to execute a command as a superuser

Comment: Running things as root certainly tends to solve permissions problems, but in the same way that deleting code removes bugs.  It's worth learning about @TeTeT's solution.

Answer (score -2):

Using the..

> $ sudo bluefish

Command in the terminal,
fixed the issue, it works well!!

> Problem Solved!!

Comment: To everyone who reads this by accident: ***Do not do this!*** Running something as root which does not need elevated rights begs for trouble.